# How Can I create ROS Multiwaypoints?[I tried some ways in addition but it didn't work]

Tags: python, navigation, ros, waypoint

I want to create multi-waypoints and moove robot according to them. I wrote the code below there but when i run the code with Gazebo and RVIZ i take an error (image)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81lh9.png)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
import actionlib
from move_base_msgs.msg import MoveBaseAction, MoveBaseGoal

def get_user_input():
    x = float(input("X koordinatını girin: "))
    y = float(input("Y koordinatını girin: "))
    orientation = float(input("Yönü (radyan cinsinden) girin: "))
    return x, y, orientation

def move_to_waypoint(x, y, orientation):
    client = actionlib.SimpleActionClient('move_base', MoveBaseAction)
    client.wait_for_server()

    goal = MoveBaseGoal()
    goal.target_pose.header.frame_id = 'map'
    goal.target_pose.pose.position.x = x
    goal.target_pose.pose.position.y = y
    goal.target_pose.pose.orientation.z = orientation
    goal.target_pose.pose.orientation.w = 1.0

    client.send_goal(goal)
    client.wait_for_result()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        rospy.init_node('waypoint_navigation', anonymous=True)

        while True:
            x, y, orientation = get_user_input()
            move_to_waypoint(x, y, orientation)

    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

I tried 2d pose estimate from rviz and give the robot different goals but again i have that error

Comment: I would check if: 1. Robot is not surrounded or is not on top of occupied costmap cell. 2. Your given goal is reachable, inside costmap and is not on occupied cell (in RViz visualize costmaps and goal pose). 3. Your way of setting orientation seems wrong. You assume that orientation.z is euclidian rotation around z axis which is not. It's quaternion and there are special rules that X, Y, Z W components must follow (they should add up to unit quaternion). You should input euler angle and transform it quaternion using quaternion_from_euler() or similar. Also make sure it's in radians not degrees